# I want fetch and show image in a table data form not in image title form in a crud from a database but unable to preview image in codeigniter,php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Modal Form and Button code(View File)

```
    <form action="" method="post" id="coach_form">
       <div class="form-group">
         <label for="">Coach Image</label>
         <input type="file" class="form-control" id="coach_img" name="coach_img">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label for="">Coach Type</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="coach_type">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label for="">Coach Name</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="coach_name">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label for="">Coach Designation</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="coach_designation">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label for="">Coach Location</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="coach_location">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label for="">Coach Description</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="coach_description">
       </div>
    </form>
    </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add_coach">Add Data</button>
      </div>
```

Table In which I am fetching data from database

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Coach Image</th>
          <th>Coach Type</th>
          <th>Coach Name</th>
          <th>Coach Designation</th>
          <th>Coach Location</th>
          <th>Coach Description</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
          <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
    </table>
```

Ajax code for fetching as data is submitted successfully

```
    function fetch(){
       $.ajax({
         url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>FetchCoach",
         type: "post",
         dataType: "json",
         success:function(data)
         {
            //console.log(data);
            var tbody = "";
            var i = "1";
            
            for(var key in data){
                tbody += "<tr>";
                tbody += "<td>"+ i++ + "</td>";
                tbody += "<td>"+ data[key]['coach_img'] + "</td>";
                tbody += "<td>"+ data[key]['coach_type'] + "</td>";
                tbody += "<td>"+ data[key]['coach_name'] + "</td>";
                tbody += "<td>"+ data[key]['coach_designation'] + "</td>";
                tbody += "<td>"+ data[key]['coach_location'] + "</td>";
                tbody += "<td>"+ data[key]['coach_description'] + "</td>";
                tbody += `<td>
                <a href = "#" id="delete_data" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger" value="${data[key]['coach_id']}"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
                <a href = "#" id="edit_data"class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info" value="${data[key]['coach_id']}"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
                        </td>`
                tbody += "</tr>";
            }
            $("#tbody").html(tbody);
        }
       });
     }
    fetch();
```

Controller Code for fetch Coach

```
    public function FetchCoach()
    {
      if($this->session->userdata('email')=="" && $this->session->userdata('password')=="")
      {
           $this->load->view('Admin/index');
      }
      else
      {
           if($this->input->is_ajax_request())
           {
                $posts = $this->adm->FetchCoach();
                echo json_encode($posts);
           }
      }
    }
```

Modal Code for fetch function

```
    public function FetchCoach()
    {
       $query = $this->db->get('coach');
       if(count($query->result() ) > 0)
       {
          return $query->result();
       }    
    }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6Kfu.png

I don't want to use dataTable jquery syntax please help me if possible without dataTable or most possibly to less edit the above code. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you provide more information about your database?
are you saving your image in blob format / text / something else?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Hi58cKw.png

Comment: please check the image @kirb

Comment: are you saving the image in url / base64?

Comment: no sir  you can see the database structure  image mentioned above @kirb